# Simple form validation test - Change border color for empty result

Tags: php, css, input, colors

I have this simple login form I'm testing. I'm using PHP, XAMPP, testing in Chrome.

This is the code for the form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">

    <label>User: </label>
    <input type="text" name="user" <?php if($errors){echo 'style="border:1px solid red;"';}?>>
    <?php echo '<script>console.log("Value for $errors: '.$errors.'")</script>';?> 

    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" <?php if($errors){echo "style='border:1px solid red;'";}?>>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This code is part of login.php, and at the very beginning, I have the following PHP lines:

```
<?php

session_start();

$user = "";
$password = "";
$errors = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        }
    }else{
        $errors = 1;
    }

    if(!empty(isset($_POST['password']))){
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    }else{
        $errors = 1;
    }

    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

}

?>
```

The action attribute in the form calls itself (calls the same file --> login.php)
In the PHP script, I try to achieve that if the form was submitted, then perform all the validation, etc. As regards the simple validation, I try assign the POST values received to the variables, IF what was received EXISTS AND IT'S NOT EMPTY. If empty or non-existant --> $errors = 1;

The thing is.. if there are errors with the two inputs, I want them to change their border color to red. So I did:

```
<label>User: </label>
<input type="text" name="user" <?php if($errors == 1){echo 'style="border:1px solid red;"';}?>>
<?php echo '<script>console.log("Value for $errors: '.$errors.'")</script>';?>
```

The last lines I've added to try to print in console the value of $errors, which always shows 0.

I've tried a little redirection using empty($user), and when submitting the form without touching the inputs, it indeed shows that the values are empty. Still, I don't fully get why being empty, $errors always has value 0.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `0` and `1` instead of `true` and `false`? Answer posted anyway

Comment: Mainly because I'm just learning, I've actually tried true/false when trying to print to console, but as it returned nothing, then I kept the numbers

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to log these in the JS console. Just use `var_dump() instead.` `var_dump( $errors );`

Comment: @NathanDawson because when I hit submit button, it refreshes... so I can't see the var_dumps on screen :/ I don't know how to actually submit, get that there are errors, and get back to the login with the red borders in the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not needed to go back on @Nathan-Dawson comment/answer about the way you need to check values, it's all said. Here's a slightly different approach: I added warning messages before/after so you can improve user's experience and it (hopefully) shows you how you can check values.

PHP side

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$errors = 0; // so you don't get 'red' applied without submitting the form

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(isset($_POST['user'])){ // check for POST'd value
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    // $errors = 0; <- $errors would remain '0' but not needed, just for the logic
    } else {
    $errors = 1; // form is processed but $user is POST'd empty
    }
} else {
    $errors = $errors; // needed if one field is set but not the other one
   // so we don't set $errors back to '0'
}

// same logic applies to 'password' -> no need to comment it out again :)

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    } else {
    $errors = 1;
    }
} else {
    $errors = $errors;
}

// added this to show users if they forgot something or not
if($errors == 0) {
$warning_mess = "Form fields have been filled, thx !";
} else { 
$warning_mess = "Please fill all fields before submitting."; 
}

// before submitting, give users a warning about fields
} else { $warning_mess = "Form fields need to be filled"; }

?>
```

the FORM side

```
<input type="text" name="user"
<?php if($errors == "1"){ echo 'style="border:1px solid red;"'; } ?> />
```

I just added the checking upon value of '$errors' with `==` to make sure we had a 0/1 -> it can be useful if you want later to make a difference and set up a customized error handling message for each field.

Of course, you need to trim and check and sanitize all data coming from users

Comment: Hi @OldPadawan! Nice, thanks! I can see errors now! But this line --> $errors = 0; // so you don't get 'red' applied without submitting the form does all the opposite :/ The borders appear in red without submitting. I've tried a var_dump($errors); right after that line, and prints int(0), but then at the end I print the variable again and it's already 1 (without submitting)

Comment: not when I tested though... It's set up in order to **not** have red bordered inputs without submitting, when you 1st reach the page (or if fields are ok). Do you have any other stuff in this code ?

Comment: Thank youuu! It's working correctly now! :D just opened and closed the window.. Thanks for the comments and the explanation! :D

Answer (score 0):

There's a flaw in the way you're checking the values.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['user'] ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['user'] ) ) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
    }
} else {
    $errors = 1;
}
```

Your form has a field titled `user` which is being submit therefore `$_POST['user']` will be set. If it is set then it doesn't matter whether or not it's empty, your code won't change `$error` to 1. You have a nested loop which isn't accounting for that.

`empty()` is going to check if it's set too so you don't need `isset()`.

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST['user'] ) ) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
} else {
    $errors = 1;
}
```

The same should apply to password. Combining `empty()` with `isset()` doesn't make sense. Copy the approach from user.

Comment: Hi! Yes, just moments ago I've tried another way of writing empty() with isset() and was working fine (with $errors changing the value, but not the border color), but I see what you mean, and have changed the code to what you posted, thank you very much :) It still doesn't work though, the border color of the inouts is not changing after submit :/